# How can I filter table based on another tables data having condition?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10

This is `folders` table:

```
+------------+
| id  name   |
|------------|
|  1  dir1   |
|  2  dir2   |
+------------+
```

This is `files` table:

```
+------------------------------+
| id  folder_id  name  deleted |
|------------------------------|
|  1  1          file1 true    |
|  2  1          file2 false   |
|  1  2          file3 true    |
|  2  2          file4 true    |
+------------------------------+
```

As you can see, `dir1` and `dir2` has 2 files per dir. But in `dir1` only one file deleted and one file is available. However, `dir2` has 2 files but both of them deleted. So no files remains in there.

What I am trying to do is get folders table and dirs that doesn't have any files (all deleted).

So far I tried this but did not worked.

```
SELECT
    "dirs".* 
FROM
    "dirs"
    INNER JOIN "files" ON ( "files"."folder_id" = "folders"."id" ) 
WHERE
    ( "files"."deleted" IS FALSE ) 
GROUP BY
    "folders".ID 
HAVING
    COUNT ( files.ID ) != 0 /* or > 0 or == 0 */
```

Expected result:

```
+------------+
| id  name   |
|------------|
|  2  dir2   |
+------------+
```

Because `dir2` has files but all deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `where not exists`:

```
select *
from folders d
where not exists (
    select 1
    from files f
    where folder_id = d.id
    and not deleted)
```

[Working example in rextester.](https://rextester.com/DDAGDA16381)

Comment: This returns both dirs :/

Comment: I don't think so, see the [example in rextester.](https://rextester.com/DDAGDA16381)

Comment: Yup. My bad. Thanks for the example. When I look at it I found the issue on my side. It just works. Thanks!